# Creating a Trigger to update inserted values.

Tags: sql, triggers

I'm not too proficient in SQL, though I'm trying to update a value inserted into table with a trigger. For example, whenever a employee is inserted into a table, increase their salary by $100. At the moment I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON "Employee"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.department = 'Multimedia' 
THEN :NEW.salary += 1000; 
END;
/
```

Again, I don't quite have a firm grasp on SQL and any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking? Does your trigger not work? What RDBMS are you using? Did you check the database's documentation?

Comment: No my trigger does not work, and I'm a little unsure why. I'm using Oracle llg express edition and have search far and wide on the web for any sort of solution.